# how to reserve the order of multiple-selection using javascript?

Tags: javascript, multiple-select

Suppose I have want to select multiple options and also reserve the order of the selection. Please see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/agfs8m3d/) as an example.

If I select `Wyoming` and **THEN** `Amalapuram`, I want the result be `["WY","Am"]`, where the `WY` is before the `Am`, but not `["An","WY"]`.

Is this possible? Thanks guys.

Here is my HTML code,

```
<select multiple id="e1" style="width:300px">
        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
        <option value="Am">Amalapuram</option>
        <option value="An">Anakapalli</option>
        <option value="Ak">Akkayapalem</option>
        <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
    </select>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" >Select All

<input type="button" id="button" value="check Selected">
```

and js code,

```
$("#e1").select2();
$("#checkbox").click(function(){
    if($("#checkbox").is(':checked') ){
        $("#e1 > option").prop("selected","selected");
        $("#e1").trigger("change");
    }else{
        $("#e1 > option").removeAttr("selected");
         $("#e1").trigger("change");
     }
});

$("#button").click(function(){
       alert($("#e1").val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a very long and boring way of doing this: Subscribe to the change event on the select2, and keep track of the selected values yourself.

Here's the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Nisarg0/agfs8m3d/2/

```
var e1Values = [];

$("#e1").select2().on('change', function(e){
    console.log(e, e.val);

  if(e1Values.length < e.val.length) {
    // Add the value when a new item is selected.
    e.val.forEach(function(item, index){
        if(e1Values.indexOf(item) == -1) {
        e1Values.push(item);
      }
    });
  } else {
    // Remove the value when an item is deselected.
    e1Values.forEach(function(item, index){
        if(e.val.indexOf(item) == -1) {
        e1Values.splice(index, 1);
      }
    });
  }

  console.log("Current value: ", e1Values);
});
```